# Logback or slf4j logging in groovy unit tests with Maven and GMaven?

Tags: maven, groovy, slf4j, logback, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to get logging enabled in my Grovvy unit tests that I am running with Cucumber-jvm.

In my tests I have imported:

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
```

Then added

```
@Slf4j
```

However, when I run any of these commands:

```
mvn test -Dgmaven.logging=DEBUG
mvn test -Dgmaven.logging=TRACE
```

This method only prints out '[WARN] log.isWarnEnabled()'

```
void debugLogging(){
    println("~~~~~ debugLogging() ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    if(log.isTraceEnabled()){
        println("log.isTraceEnabled()")
        log.trace("log.isTraceEnabled()")
    }
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
        println("log.isDebugEnabled()")
        log.debug("log.isDebugEnabled()")
    }
    if(log.isInfoEnabled()){
        println("log.isInfoEnabled()")
        log.info("log.isInfoEnabled()")
    }
    if(log.isWarnEnabled()){
        println("log.isWarnEnabled()")
        log.warn("log.isWarnEnabled()")
    }
}
```

Here is my ./src/test/resources/logback.xml :

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Use level="DEBUG" for more detailed logging -->
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

How can I change the log level in my unit test?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the hard way that GMaven does not use logback. The plugin is designed to leverage Sonatype's default SLF4J provided, called [gossip](https://github.com/jdillon/gossip) (Described in the GMaven advanced [configuration](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Advanced+Configuration))

So this might explain why your *logback.xml* file was ignored (Although one would think SLF4J calls would be redirected to the configured runtime provider when run from unit tests)

To pass the *gmaven.logging* property into you're unit tests you could try setting it within the surefire plugin as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <gmaven.logging>DEBUG</gmaven.logging>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Hope this helps.

## Update

I came across this problem when developing a Maven plugin. My challenge was to capture logging calls originating in a library that did not using SLF4J....

To solve this problem, I added one of the bridging APIs to my plugin dependencies section as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    ..
    ..
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

This will re-route commons logging calls over to your SLF4J implementation, which in the case of Maven will be gossip.

Comment: I was already putting '-Dgmaven.logging=DEBUG' to the command-line. But I did add this to surefire just in case, and that did not change anything. Still only [WARN] logs are being printed. all others are ignored.

Comment: @MickKnutson What a pain.... What does your runtime classpath look like? Any chance these logging calls are being intercepted by another logging provider like log4j? (Often included as a transitive dependency)

Comment: Does anyone have a working .gossip/config.properties that will work with gossip? I cannot get it configured.

Comment: @MickKnutson In my case I just went with the default settings. Setting the gmaven.logging property allowed me to set the log level. In my case I was developing a plugin (rather than attempting to run unit tests). I've included details of what I did. Hope this helps.